# SQL query to pick all active employees and terminated employees only during a specific period

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have written a query to get both active and inactive employees from a table-

```
select papf.name,papf.empl_id,papf.assignment_status_type
from per_all_people_f papf,
per_periods_of_service ppos
where papf.person_id = ppos.person_id
AND (ppos.ACTUAL_TERMINATION_DATE is null or trunc(ACTUAL_TERMINATION_DATE) BETWEEN TO_CHAR (:from_date,
'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_CHAR (:TO_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
AND ASSIGNMENT_STATUS <> 'Terminated - No Payroll'
```

This query will fetch all ACTIVE and INACTIVE assignments(terminated-Payroll eligible). I want that the inactive assignments/terminated-Payroll eligible assignment status is only fetched for the date passed i.e. :from_date and :to_date along with all ACTIVE assignments.

I added a condition that `actual_termination_date is between these dates to pick the Terminated-Payroll` eligible or it is null for the active assignments but this query is fetching Terminated-Payroll eligible even when the actual_termination_date is not in those dates.

Just to add Terminated-Payroll eligible corresponds to INACTIVE IN papf.assignment_status_type

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Why are you choosing NOT to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `TO_CHAR (:from_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')`, You don't have to convert it to `CHAR` as you are comparing it against the date. (both `:from_date` and `:to_date`)

If `:from_date` is date then simply use the `:from_date` and if `:from_date` is a string then convert it to date and then use it as `to_date(:from_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')` -- applies to `:to_date` also